# Shimming Debugger.IsAttached?

Tags: c#, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I have a method that checks to see if the debugger is attached so that it can suspend certain logging functions that are better handles by the debugger.

I want to test this functionality using the Unit Test framework built into Visual Studio 2013. I tried adding a Fake System assembly, which generates the System and mscorlib fakes. I then went into mscorlib.fakes and added:

```
<ShimGeneration>
    <Add FullName="System.Diagnostics.Debugger!"/>
</ShimGeneration>
```

But the resulting `System.Diagnostics.Fakes.ShimDebugger` does not have an `IsAttachedGet` property as I would expect for the `IsAttached` property. Break, Launch, and NotifyOfCrossThreadDependency have properties, but IsAttached, IsLogging, and Log do not have properties.

Am I missing a configuration, or is this simply one of those types that cannot be shimmed according to Limitations on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx?

Comment: They all have the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] attribute, surely the underlying problem.  Do consider how you are going to debug your unit test :)

Comment: Hopefully the shim takes precedence, so the code under test ought to either see that there is or is not a debugger attached regardless of whether I'm debugging it or not. Would the shim affect assemblies that the debugger needs? That would make sense as a reason to prevent the shimming...